# How can I install latex on Ubuntu 20.04.5

Tags: apt, software-installation, latex

I cannot install latex on Ubuntu 20.04.5 via the commands:

```
sudo apt install -y texlive  
sudo apt install -y texlive-full
```

I got the response: no texlive and no texlive-full

Could you please help me?

Comment: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-tex-live-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-a-free-typesetting-system/

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Yes I did run sudo apt update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are packages that are in the universe repository. If you cannot install them, then "universe" may not be enabled.

Start the utility "software and updates". On the first tab, "Ubuntu software", make sure "Community-maintained free and open-source software" is checked.

If it does not work after that, then try changing your download mirror.

`texlive` and `texlive-full` are metapackages. `texlive` installs already quite a lot of packages, in total about 270 MB and will suit many users. `texlive-full` installs everything possible, and will take 6,1 GB. So you need to install only the one that best matches your use case. Additional packages can be installed anytime if needed.

Comment: Your answer helped solve my problem. Thanks a lot.